# xquery execute xquery against a hidden field containing xml

Tags: html, xml, xquery

Hello i have some standard xml contained within a hidden field of my page. I want to be abble to execute at loading of my page an xquery contained in my page against the xml contained in the field. Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using [XQIB](http://www.xqib.org) you should be able to do this to execute an XQuery script against a value in a hidden field:

```
<script type="application/xquery">
  let $x := b:dom()//input[@name='hidden-field-name]
  (: do stuff with $x:)
  return (: result :)
</script>
```

If you need to create the XQuery dynamically, I think you could do something like this in a JS  function (untested):

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'application/xquery';
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode('*xquery code goes here*'));
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Hat tip to @grtjn for suggesting XQIB in an answer to another question.

Comment: thanks wst i am gonna try this. do this mean that if i have this $x i can do something like this with it? for $x 
where $x/price>30
return $x/title or do i miss some parts of it

Comment: Here is my code but not working... how to use doc with a variable
`<script type="application/xquery">
 b:alert(
 let $x  as element() :=  b:dom()//input[@name="Language"]
for $y in $x/ArrayOfMediaAssetInfoLite
return $y/data(@value)
)
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world page.</h1>
<input type="hidden" name="Language" value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?>
&lt;ArrayOfMediaAssetInfoLite xmlns:i=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; > &lt;MediaAssetInfoLite> &lt;Title>s&lt;/Title>[...]iaAssetInfoLite>"
/></body>
</html>`

Comment: @Fongios What is not working? Are you getting an error message? You can use jQuery to convert a string to XML: `var xmlData = $('<data></data>');`

Comment: it seems i cannot access to $x/ArrayOfMediaAssetInfoLite like this. if i remove /ArrayOfMediaAssetInfoLite i can display the value. it seems the xml navigation notation does not work

Comment: how would i use jquery to change the variable to xml and then use the xml in the doc() xquery function.

Comment: @Fongios It sounds like your problem is that the value is a string, not XML. You could use another function to convert the value to XML, and call that from XQuery. If you are having trouble with jQuery, I would recommend looking at the many questions on SO already posted on the subject, or create a new question.

Comment: i tried this. unfortunatly still does not work. it seems it cannot recognize it as xml. you can try run the code on http://www.sourcepod.com/hyncto49-18347

Comment: @Fongios First, note that your XML string does not appear to be serialized correctly. The samples included with the XQIB download don't seem to work on my browsers (Safari, Chrome), so I don't think I can help you test this. A couple general suggestions: 1) If XQIB only queries DOM elements, then you could try inserting XML into the DOM, and then query the DOM, 2) Create an XHTML version of your XML elements (`<div name='book' category='cooking'><div name='title' lang='en'>Everyday...`), store them in a hidden div, and query that either before or after you convert it back to your schema.